# non-conformable arguments error from lmer when trying to extract information from the model matrix

Tags: lme4, splines, model.matrix

I have some longitudinal data from which I'd like to get the predicted means at specified times.  The model includes 2 terms, their interaction and a spline term for the time variable.  When I try to obtain the predicted means, I get "Error in mm %*% fixef(m4) : non-conformable arguments"

I've used the sleep data set from lmer to illustrate my problem. First, I import the data and create a variable "age" for my interaction

```
sleep <- as.data.frame(sleepstudy)  #get the sleep data
# create fake variable for age with 3 levels
set.seed(1234567)
sleep$age <- as.factor(sample(1:3,length(sleep),rep=TRUE))
```

Then I run my lmer model

```
library(lme4)
library(splines)
m4 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + ns(Days, df=4) + age + Days:age + (Days | Subject), sleep)
```

Finally, I create the data and matrix needed to obtain predicted means

```
#new data frame for predicted means
d <- c(0:9)  # make a vector of days = 0 to 9 to obtain predictions for each day
newdat <- as.data.frame(cbind(Days=d, age=rep(c(1:3),length(d))))
newdat$Days <- as.numeric(as.character(newdat$Days))
newdat$age <- as.factor(newdat$age)

# create a matrix 
mm<-model.matrix(~Days + ns(Days, df=4) + age + Days:age, newdat)  
newdat$pred<-mm%*%fixef(m4)
```

It's at this point that I get the error:
Error in mm %*% fixef(m4) : non-conformable arguments

I can use predict to get the means

```
newdat$pred <- predict(m4, newdata=newdat, re.form=NA)
```

which works fine, but I want to be able to calculate a confidence interval, so I need a conformable matrix.

I read somewhere that the problem may be that lmer creates aliases (I can't find that post). This comment was made with regards to not being able to use effect() for a similar task.  I couldn't quite understand how to overcome this problem.  Moreover, I recall that post was a little old and hoped the alias problem may no longer be relevant.

If anyone has a suggestion for what I may be doing wrong, I'd appreciate the feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: In the example you give, you get the message `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient`.  This means the number of fixed effects in the model is less than the number in `mm`, which is why you are getting the error message

Comment: Yes, aosmith, I do get that message.  It disappears if the model includes only the spline; i.e. :      m4 <- lmer(Reaction ~ ns(Days, df=4) + age + Days:age + (Days | Subject), sleep)

Comment: Sorry, correction, it disappears in the univariate (spline only) model, but anyway the error is associated with the use of the splines.

Comment: did you read my answer ... ?

Comment: Yes, @BenBolker, I did read it - I was getting some errors that I needed to work out first.  I have responded to your answer directly.  In addition, I identified 2 oddities of these example data, which need new posts, but I note them here for completeness: 1) I thought using a seed would generate the same levels of age each time, but this oddly is not so, hence your comment “## next line happens to sample only 2 and 3 ...”; 2) predict and this method give different results when the factor variable uses labels that have an alphabetical order different to the numbering order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things here.

- you need to drop columns to make your model matrix commensurate with the fixed effect vector that was actually fitted (i.e., commensurate with the model matrix that was actually used for fitting, after dropping collinear columns)
- for additional confusion, you happened to only sample ages 2 and 3 (out of a possible {1,2,3})

I've cleaned up the code a little bit ...

```
library("lme4")
library("splines")
sleep <- sleepstudy  #get the sleep data
set.seed(1234567)
## next line happens to sample only 2 and 3 ...
sleep$age <- as.factor(sample(1:3,length(sleep),rep=TRUE))
length(levels(sleep$age))  ## 2
```

Fit model:

```
m4 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + ns(Days, df=4) +
    age + Days:age + (Days | Subject), sleep)
## message; fixed-effect model matrix is 
##    rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
```

Check fixed effects:

```
f1 <- fixef(m4)
length(f1)  ## 7
f2 <- fixef(m4,add.dropped=TRUE)
length(f2)  ## 8
```

We *could* use this extended version of the fixed effects (which has an `NA` value in it), but this would just mess us up by propagating `NA` values through the computation ...

Check model matrix:

```
X <- getME(m4,"X")
ncol(X)  ## 7
(which.dropped <- attr(getME(m4,"X"),"col.dropped"))
## ns(Days, df = 4)4 
##             6
```

New data frame for predicted means

```
d <- 0:9  
## best to use data.frame() directly, avoid cbind()
##   generate age based on *actual* levels in data
newdat <- data.frame(Days=d,
   age=factor(rep(levels(sleep$age),length(d))))
```

Create a matrix:

```
mm <- model.matrix(formula(m4,fixed.only=TRUE)[-2], newdat)
mm <- mm[,-which.dropped]   ## drop redundant columns
## newdat$pred <- mm%*%fixef(m4)    ## works now
```

Added by sianagh: Code to obtain confidence intervals and plot the data:

```
predFun <- function(x) predict(x,newdata=newdat,re.form=NA)
newdat$pred <- predFun(m4)
bb <- bootMer(m4,
   FUN=predFun,
    nsim=200)  
## nb. this produces an error message on its first run, 
## but not on subsequent runs (using the development version of lme4)
bb_ci <- as.data.frame(t(apply(bb$t,2,quantile,c(0.025,0.975))))
names(bb_ci) <- c("lwr","upr")
newdat <- cbind(newdat,bb_ci)
```

Plot:

```
plot(Reaction~Days,sleep)
with(newdat,
    matlines(Days,cbind(pred,lwr,upr),
            col=c("red","green","green"),
            lty=2,
            lwd=c(3,2,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Indeed this solution does work. I had planned to use bootMer to generate prediction intervals see(r-bloggers.com/confidence-intervals-for-prediction-in-glmms). However, these data don't seem to be able to support that. If I run the following: `predFun<-function(.) mm%*%fixef(.)` `bb<-bootMer(m4,FUN=predFun,nsim=200)` I get 2 warnings: `unable to evaluate scaled gradient ` and `Model failed to converge: degenerate Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues.` I think the problem is that the data can't support the function. Do you agree?

Comment: On the basis of this example I have fixed a bug in lme4.  How hard would it be for you to install the development version from Github to test it (i.e. `library("devtools"); install_github("lme4/lme4")` ?

Comment: Using the development version, on first run the same error appears, but still produces estimates.  On subsequent runs there's no error warning.  Estimates are different each time (as they should be).  It's unclear to me why the error disappears after the first run.

Comment: For those interested, I encountered another problem with this analysis, which pointed to the need to carefully construct the model matrix (if using it). Post is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346755/predict-and-model-matrix-give-different-predicted-means-within-levels-of-a-facto

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused due to the drift component, if you put

```
allowdrift=FALSE
```

into your auto.arima prediction it will be fixed.